# Show that this bilinear transformation is an abelian group

Tags: group-theory

if $z$ denotes any complex number, then show that the bilinear trnasformation $$f(z)={az+b\over cz+d}$$ , $ad-bc\ne0$, $a,b,c,d\in C$ is an abelian group.

There is no composition defined. Is there a default composition for such types of groups ?

Comment: The transformation itself is not a group. The set of all fractional linear transformations (with non-vanishing determinant) is a group with composition of maps as multiplication, but it's not abelian.

Comment: The normal function composition works. The identity mapping can be figured by just setting specific values for a,b,c,d.For that observe the non-vanishing condition you have mentioned. Does that help?

Comment: @Vishesh so should i consider $f[g(x)]$ etc ? it will become huge. no ?

Comment: Not really, try looking at it as a $2 \times 2 $ matrix, of course it has to be invertible.

Comment: oh ! i solve it taking it as a $2X2$ non-singular matrix ? and considering multiplication of matrix etc ?

Comment: @AmanMittal Almost. Some matrices induce the same mapping. Find which.

Comment: Yes, you are on the right track. That way the inverse and Identity are quite obvious.

Comment: -vishesh - ok, but i do not understand why that will work ? how is composition of functions similar to matrix multiplication ? @DanielFischer

Comment: In general, you can represent _linear_ maps by matrices, and the composition of linear maps then corresponds to matrix multiplication. For fractional linear transformations, if you compute the composition, you'll see what comes out is the matrix product. That's not just a coincidence. Function composition in full generality is not much related with matrix multiplication, of course, but we're looking at a special class of functions.

Comment: @Daniel Fischer I apologise for butting in as this was meant for him. Anyways just write the coefficients of the transformation you have given in Matrix form and see how it works in this case.

Comment: @Vishesh I don't know what you're apologising for, but apology accepted ;)

Comment: In case, you are still wondering just list $f_1(z)=\frac{a_1z+b_1}{c_1z+d_1},f_2(z)=\frac{a_2z+b_2}{c_2z+d_2}$ and compose them explicitly and see the result.The computation wont take much time.Hope this helps.

Comment: @Vishesh Yes, you cleared it for me. Thanks for the help. Please put it up as an answer.

Comment: @Daniel Oh I thought he wanted you to answer it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

List $f_1(z)=\frac{a_1z+b_1}{c_1z+d_1},f_2(z)=\frac{a_2z+b_2}{c_2z+d_2}$ and compose them explicitly and observe that this is same as Matrix multiplication of $2 \times2$ invertible matrices which is clearly not abelian in general as Daniel pointed out.